# How Healpix deal with NaN to interpolate data on the sky map?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, healpy

I have my data in this format `datapoint[37][19]` in the `phi-theta` space. But because my data can not cover the whole sky, so there is some NaN in the `datapoint` array. There is about half NaN in the whole `datapoint`. About 9/10 non-NaN values in `datapoint` are negative, about 1/10 of them are positive.

I tried this interpolation function:

```
scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline(theta,phi,datapoint.T)
```

But it returned erros. I am asking how do I interpolate the data which contains NaN, positive and negative values to the level Healpix can use it to make maps. I have a unsmoothed map made from Basemap.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is about 1) dealing with missing data, 2) dealing with NaNs, or 3) turning arbitrary data on the sphere into a Healpix map.

1) interpolating missing data on large area of the sky requires at least some statistical knowledge of your data in order to make a constrained realization of what is missing. But filling those gaps is only required if you do non-local operations (like convolutions or gradients), so it depends
what you plan to do with the data.

2) Setting the missing data to NaN will certainly screw up all the interpolation schemes available.

3) The python code below turns a data set similar to yours (as far as I can tell) into 2 Healpix maps, one using a Nearest Grip Point (NGP) sampling, the other using a BSpline interpolation.
Note that the second will most likely not work in the presence of NaNs,
while the first one is extremely robust.

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

datapoint = np.zeros((37,19), dtype=np.float)
datapoint[18,9] = 1.0
datapoint[0,9] = -1.0

nside      = 64
npix       = hp.nside2npix(nside)

# location of Healpix pixels center
ip         = np.arange(npix)
theta_rad, phi_rad = hp.pix2ang(nside, ip)

# map0 : NGP sampling
theta_deg = np.rad2deg(theta_rad)
phi_deg   = np.rad2deg(phi_rad)
hp_0      = datapoint[np.rint(phi_deg/10.).astype(int), \
                      np.rint(theta_deg/10.).astype(int)]
hp.mollview(hp_0,title='NGP map')

# map1: BSpline interpolation
from scipy.interpolate import RectSphereBivariateSpline
epsilon = 1.e-12
th_in = np.linspace(epsilon,  np.pi-epsilon, 19)
ph_in = np.linspace(epsilon,2*np.pi-epsilon, 37)
lut   = RectSphereBivariateSpline(th_in, ph_in, datapoint.T, s=1)
hp_1  = lut.ev(theta_rad, phi_rad)
hp.mollview(hp_1,title='BSpline map')

pl.show()
```